# Regex - How to pick out these integers, individually

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the following HTML that I am trying to pick apart.  For some reason I can't figure out the Regex (which, admittedly, I suck at):

```
<td class="score">
    286

        <span class="pos">(2455 of 3921)</span>

</td>
```

I'm looking to get the 3 integers out, individually.  So, basically:

- **Score = 286**
- **Place = 2455**
- **Entries = 3921**

I went through the 'numeric ranges' page on regular-expressions.info, but still can't figure it out!!!  Yes, I know it is easy... apparently my brain can't comprehend this type of logic.

I will be using it in vb.net, BTW. In case that matters.

Comment: `(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)` will capture them into three separate groups. Simply `\d+` repeated three times will match them one by one.

Comment: Where do I test that at?  I'm using regexr.com and it doesn't work.  Maybe the tester is part of my problem?  I tested that on regexstorm.net also and it seems to capture everything from 286 through 3921.

Comment: [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/opcRER/1). And - No, it doesn't capture everything from 286 through 3921 - it **matches** that. But what you're interested in are the **capture groups** 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a simple example of code that does it for you at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3Yk9Ur).

The gut looks something like:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("<td class='score'>    286          <span class='pos'>(2455 of 3921)</span> </td>")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(2).Value)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(3).Value)
End If
```

Comment: Awesome.  I had just finished writing this exact code :)  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This regex fetches all numbers in a string.

`/\d+/g;`

Comment: Can you point me to a tester (online) where this works?  I tried regexr.com and regexstorm.net - both don't show matches.